# Laravel route function add extra slash to url

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have an issue in my laravel 5.2 project.
The main page has a form which post to the following URL
`myapp.com/check` 
So i created a route for this like:

`Route::post('/check', 'StatusController@index')->name('StatusPost');`

When i open the home page, the form action URL is like:

`http://myapp.com/check/`

Here is the form code:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => route('StatusPost'), 'method' => 'post')) !!}
......
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The problem is that laravel did not recognize the `http://myapp.com/check/`, if i remove the slash at the end, it works correctly.

**EDIT**

Route.php file:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomepageController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/about', function () {
    return View::make('pages.about');
});

Route::get('/terms', function () {
    return View::make('pages.terms');
});

Route::get('/help', function () {
    return View::make('pages.help');
});

Route::get('/privacy', function () {
    return View::make('pages.privacy');
});


Route::post('/check', 'StatusController@index')->name('StatusPost');


Route::get('/{product}', 'StatusController@index')->where('product', '(.*)')->name('productStatus');
```

Any help to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: can you show us your routes file?

Comment: @WreighChristianSantos i added the content of route file, thanks

Comment: the error is MethodNotAllowed or a 404?

Comment: @WreighChristianSantos no, it redirect to `productStatus` route, `Route::get('/{product}', ...`

Comment: try switching these lines `Route::post('/check')` and `Route::get('/{product}')`

Answer (score 0):

Route you is a Route::resource  -> StatusController ?

Answer (score 0):

Both of your Routes `Route::post('/check')` and `Route::get('/{product}')` use the same Controller function `index`